# Recursive piecewise function in SymPy and summing over a list/array of coefficients

Tags: python, math, sympy

For lack of a Latex editor, here is a picture of a piecewise function that I wish to plot using Sympy. I want to pass in two arrays of the coefficients and a value for x, then evaluate it and plot the function. (Edit : there are exactly one more p than there are alphas, image updated)

[image: Piecewise Function]
This is my attempt so far (alpha and p are lists/arrays, t is a number):

```
def getf(alpha,p,t):

#Create the argument list of tuples for the SymPy.Piecewise function
argtuples = []
for n,number in enumerate(alpha):
    if n == 0:
        argtuples.append((p[0]*x, x<alpha[0]))
    elif 0<n and n<list(enumerate(alpha))[-1][0]:
        argtuples.append((p[0]*alpha[0] + Sum(p[i]*(alpha[i] - alpha[i-1]),(i,1,n)) + p[n+1]*(x-alpha[n]), alpha[n-1] <= x < alpha[n]))
    else:
        argtuples.append((p[0]*alpha[0] + Sum(p[i]*(alpha[i] - alpha[i-1]),(i,1,n)) + p[n+1]*(x-alpha[n]), x>=alpha[n]))

f = Piecewise(argtuples)
return f(t)

from sympy import Piecewise, Sum
from sympy.abc import x, i

getf([10000,50000,100000,1000000],[0.05,0.08,0.15,0.30,0.40],1000001)
```

However, I'm getting the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not Symbol". How can I reference the coefficient values that I have passed into the function, given that the array could be any length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a symbolic index on a Python list (here `i` is symbolic, since you are importing it from `abc`). If you know the list ahead of time, you should use the Python `sum` function to sum the values, instead of `Sum`.

```
sum(p[i]*(alpha[i] - alpha[i-1]) for i in range(1, n))
```

There is also another problem, which is that you have `alpha[n-1] <= x < alpha[n]`. This unfortunately won't work, due to the way Python handles chained inequalities. You have to write this as `And(alpha[n-1] <= 1, x < alpha[n])` Otherwise you will get `TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational`.

Comment: Thank you, this did help with the SymPy.And() function. However, I have reworked my code to compute the cumulative sum of the alphas before constructing the argument list. Now I think I have the cumulative sum working, but when I pass my arguments into sympy.Piecewise() I get the error: 

TypeError: __new__() takes 3 positional arguments but 7 were given

Any Idea why it won't take 7 arguments? In the docs it looks like you can supply any amount of intervals for Piecewise().

Comment: How are you creating the Piecewise? It does indeed support an arbitrary number of arguments. The TypeError may be coming from something else.